# SQL Syntax for Records with Date field to include Last Three Days

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, date

I need help with a query to pull all records where a date field is within the last three days including the current date. So if I ran query today it would pull records for 11/30, 12/1, 12/2, and 12/3. My query today just pulls records for the current date.

```
select loannumber, createdondate
from datatable as a
where     (DATEPART(m, a.CreatedOnDate) = DATEPART(m, GETDATE())) 
      AND (DATEPART(yyyy, a.CreatedOnDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())) 
      AND (DATEPART(d, a.CreatedOnDate) = DATEPART(d, GETDATE()))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look up how to use BETWEEN.  That will be your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`datediff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function allows you to calculate the differences between two dates without having to re-implement this logic yourself:

```
SELECT loannumber, createdondate
FROM   datatable as a
WHERE  DATEDIFF (day, CreatedOnDate, GETDATE()) <= 3
```